# Python Date range looping date from API

Tags: python, python-3.x

Requirement: I have to pass start_date and end_date to API and loop b/w range of dates

Example : Range of dates is `start_date = '2022-05-23'` and `end_date ='2022-05-26'`

So When I loop data from API, it should first start_date and end_date as below

```
start_date = '2022-05-23' and end_date ='2022-05-24'
start_date = '2022-05-24' and end_date ='2022-05-25'
start_date = '2022-05-25' and end_date ='2022-05-26'     
start_date = '2022-05-26' and end_date ='2022-05-27'
start_date = '2022-05-27' and end_date ='2022-05-28'
start_date = '2022-05-28' and end_date ='2022-05-29'
```

Tried as below , was able to increment start_date , not sure how to increment end_date by 1 day of start_date

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_date = "2022-05-24"
end_date = "2022-05-29"
start_dt = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
end_dt = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
delta = timedelta(days=1)
while start_dt <= end_dt:
    print(f"start_dt:{start_dt}")
    print(f"end_dt:{end_dt}")
    start_dt += delta
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import date 

start_date = "2022-05-24"
end_date = "2022-05-29"

start_dt = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
end_dt = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
gap=(end_dt-start_dt).days
print(gap)
end_dt=end_dt- timedelta(gap-1)
delta = timedelta(days=1)
for i in range(gap):
    print(f"start_dt:{start_dt}")
    print(f"end_dt:{end_dt}")
    start_dt += delta
    end_dt   += delta
```

Comment: so using this u not need to handle any temp variable

Comment: start_dt:2022-05-24 00:00:00
end_dt:2022-05-25 00:00:00
start_dt:2022-05-25 00:00:00
end_dt:2022-05-26 00:00:00
start_dt:2022-05-26 00:00:00
end_dt:2022-05-27 00:00:00
start_dt:2022-05-27 00:00:00
end_dt:2022-05-28 00:00:00
start_dt:2022-05-28 00:00:00
end_dt:2022-05-29 00:00:00

Comment: Super thanks , @user16812832 .. If I want to loop every 10 mins from the date how can i achieve that .. example ```start_dt:2022-05-24 00:00:00 end_dt:2022-05-24 00:10:00 start_dt:2022-05-24 00:10:00 end_dt:2022-05-24 00:20:00 ```

Answer (score 1):

> [...] *not sure how to increment end_date by 1 day of start_date*

```
temp_dt = start_dt + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(f"start_dt:{start_dt}")
print(f"end_dt:{temp_dt}")
```

This should work fine.

Comment: it went on looping continously . It should be looped until `end_date = "2022-05-29"`

Comment: Oh, so why don't you just create a temporary variable? Let me edit...